# Stuck at the boot screen

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac

I'm running Yosemite. While booting up I get stuck at the screen with the following screen.[image]

Is it a serious issue? If yes, how can I save my data?

Answer (score 1):

The prohibitory means the system has found an installed OS but was unable to boot it.

Your possibilities are :

- Boot into safe mode (Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> at boot and if it boots, fixing your permissions
- Backing you drive using another Mac and [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725?locale=en_US)